# Insert Count of DISTINCT Value into Same Table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to count results in a table and then inser the counted total into a field in the same table, but the total I am getting is for the whole table and not the specific Id

Here is the some sample data:

```
Id  Customer    Invoice#    Count of Invoice
22  12345       6789        
23  777         11223       
24  777         11223
25  777         2341
```

I need to count how many times DISTINCT Invoice# appears for each Customerand then put that value into the Count of Invoice field for each row for that Customer, for example given the data above Count of Invoice should be 1 in the first row and 2 for the next 3 rows.

I have this, but it seems to Count all the DISTINCT Invoice# in total in the table and puts the same value in every row.

```
UPDATE [Insight].[dbo].[Rev]
SET [Count of Invoice] = 
(SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT [Invoice#])
  FROM [Insight].[dbo].[Rev]
WHERE Customer = Customer)
```

Comment: This screams of a bad design. Why are you putting the count of distinct invoices for a customer here? That should either be done on demand (probably the best option) or stored in the customer table.

Comment: It's purely for analysis, the data isn't used in a "live" environment as such.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Customer = Customer` in your subquery will be resolved against the subquery table; effectively meaning that it will resolve to true for **every** row (unless `Customer` has a value of `NULL`). This should work:

```
UPDATE R
SET [Count of Invoice] = DC.DistinctCount
FROM [Insight].[dbo].[Rev] R
     CROSS APPLY (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT ca.[Invoice#]) AS DistinctCount
                  FROM [Insight].[dbo].[Rev] ca
                  WHERE ca.Customer = R.Customer) DC;
```

Answer (score 2):

You need `alias` :

```
UPDATE r
   SET r.[Count of Invoice] = (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT r1.[Invoice#])
                               FROM [Insight].[dbo].[Rev] r1
                               WHERE r.Customer = r1.Customer)
FROM [Insight].[dbo].[Rev] r;
```